# What is the common way of automating image compression for front-end development?

Tags: image, automation, compression, pipeline

I'm working on a project of campaign pages which often contain many static image files. Manually compress them during development is a pain in the ass.

So, I've created a script to compress images over pre-commit hook. Whenever someone commits with image files, the files will be compressed.

But I wonder what is the common way of automation of image compression for front-end development?

I've checked online, and it seems that CI/CD could also be a good place to handle the job. Or maybe let the server side (image proxy) to handle it?

Many thanks!